# Why does the following not have a max/min?

Tags: calculus, optimization, constraints

> Let $f$ and $g$ be functions on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined respectively by
>
> $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{3}x^3 - \frac{3}{2}y^2 + 2x$$ and
>
> $$g(x,y)=x−y.$$
>
> Consider the problems of maximizing and minimizing $f$ on the
>   constraint set $$C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,g(x,y)=0\}.$$
>
> Options:
>
> - $f$ has a maximum at $(1,1)$ and minimum at $(2,2)$
> - $f$ has a maximum at $(1,1)$, but does not have a minimum
> - $f$ has a minimum at $(2,2)$, but does not have a maximum
> - $f$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum

I got a max at $(1,1)$ and min at $(2,2)$, by taking $g(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$ and thus differentiating: $$\begin{align*}
\underset{x,y\in\mathcal{R}}{\max(\min)} \frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{3}{2}y^2+2x \ & \ st.\ x-y=0\\ 
\Leftrightarrow \underset{x\in\mathcal{R}}{\max(\min)} \frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2+2x
\end{align*}$$

but the correct answer is:

$f$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum.

How so?

Comment: Explain how you got your answer briefly , otherwise we won't be able to help you. If there's a calculation mistake previously not obvious, we can point it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a *local* maximum and a *local* minimum. There is no *global* maximum because for $x=y \rightarrow \pm\infty$ the objective function $f(x,y) \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

You may also spot this by taking the limits of $\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2+2x$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you obtained the conclusion by letting 
$$\left(\frac 13 x^3-\frac 32 x^2+2x\right)'=0,$$
which yields that 
$$(x-2)(x-1)=0,$$
and so you concluded that the function achieves extrema at $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, respectively. This is, however, not true, because the first-order condition only characterizes **local extrema** rather than global ones, or in other words, it is the necessary condition for maxima or minima, but not sufficient. In your question, it is obvious that when $x\to +\infty$, the cubic term is dominating and hence the value diverges to $+\infty$, and when $x\to -\infty$, the cubic term is also dominating and hence the value diverges to $-\infty$.